# Using objects I didn't allocate or initialize

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, object, methods, initialization

I just wrote some code. It has my own custom made class. In that custom made class called 'WonderfulNumbers' I have a method that looks like this

```
- (NSString *)storedNumberAsString {
NSString *stringToReturn = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Hello World"];
return [stringToReturn autorelease];
}
```

I obviously then #import "WonderfulNumbers" into the main and etc
then in my main  I have an IBAction.
it reads like the following

```
-(IBAction)displaySomeText:(id)sender {
    WonderfulNumbers *myNumber = [[WonderfulNumbers  alloc]init];// Step 1
    NSString *numberString = [myNumber storedNumberAsString];// Step 2
    [textView insertText:numberString];// Step 3
    //textView is a variable  of NSTextView.
    [myNumber release];// Step 4
}
```

I get the step by step process, and the logic behind this. 
What I like to know and try to reassure to my self is what exactly is happening at step 2.

I understand Step 1, 3 and 4.

But step 2, I crated an NSString variable called 'numberString' and it obviously holds the object  called 'myNumber' with the method described above applied to it. Makes sense.

What I want to know is, I never allocated or initialized the 'numberString' object of NSString class. How am I able to then use it. 
I know I don't release it since it's never allocated .. but did I initialize it by just doing [myNumber storedNumberAsString];  ?

A slight explanation would be awesome. Thank's to those that reply.

P.S. I know that everything in objective-c is an object but just for the sake of this argument, since 'numberString' is not technically "created by allocate and init" is it right to call that a variable?

I think I know the differences between the two but just want reassurance.

Thanks.

Comment: "numberString" stores the pointer to the value returned by "storedNumberAsString", which is the NSString @"Hello World".  "numberString" is not itself an object, it just holds an object pointer.  (You need to not think of the objects themselves as having names -- just the locations holding pointers to them have names.)

Comment: (It's kind of like you have an office with 3 desks named Sam, Joe, and Pete.  The desks have these names regardless of who's sitting at them.  The guy sitting at Sam could move to Pete, and then he'd be known as "Pete", since there was no other name for him.)

Comment: Awesome, it's all falling into place now. Thanks a bunch man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing `NSString *stringToReturn` to the return value of `[myNumber storedNumberAsString]`. Inside `storedNumberAsString` you can see that it returns an `NSString` reference, properly allocated and all, so it's fine to use.

The key here is `autorelease`, which causes the object to be released automatically “sometime later” (actually when the topmost autorelease pool is released, which, unless you changed it yourself, tends to happen after each iteration of the event loop).

The convention in Objective-C is that if you `alloc` or `retain` an object, or get an object from a method whose name begins with `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`, you are responsible for releasing it. Otherwise you can assume it will be released by someone else (e.g., later via `autorelease`). Since `storedNumberAsString` does not begin with `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`, you don't need to release it. Meanwhile the implementation of `storedNumberAsString` must ensure that the object it `alloc`s gets released -- in this case that is done by calling `autorelease` on it.

Comment: Thank's for that. 

The code works fine when I run & build it. It's solid as far as I can tell. 

My concern is mostly that I get what's exactly going on.. into my head. 

What I'm trying to get in my head is "at what part in this whole process did I exactly allocate the 'numberString' object. 

Thank you so much again.